# merge sort without extra memory

Tags: memory, mergesort

is there any condition in which merge sort can be done without extra memory
my prof said it has and he will give bonus point on that.

Comment: Please mark homework with the [homework] tag.  And, please do your own homework.  If I give you the answer, I don't get the credit.  That's hardly fair.

Comment: Why should you get a bonus point for posting on an internet forum?

Comment: Even worse, if we do your homework you will come to an interview at one the companies we work for unprepared. And one of us will have to show you the door.

Comment: ...the answer to this can be found easily on Google.

Answer (score 1):

You want to google in place merge sort.

Here is one of the result :
http://thomas.baudel.name/Visualisation/VisuTri/inplacestablesort.html

Answer (score 0):

Use linked list. This will avoid the O(n) extra space needed during Mergeing of 2 lists. However, you cannot do anything about the space taken by recursion calls i.e O(lg(n)).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the answer to this is to use [in-place merge sort](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/mergesort.html)

Comment: [in-place merge sort](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/mergesort.html): _In place mergesort with arrays is a complex problem beyond the scope of this discussion._

Answer (score -2):

Given that this is a homework question, I can only point you to *The Art of Computer Programming*. A good programmer should be able to use the standard references in our field to research a question such as this.